# get width and height of bitmap when rotate bitmap android?

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation

i'm learning how to rotate bitmap in android, but i have problem when get width and height of bitmap.. how to fix it ?

this my code;

```
// Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();

            if(degree!=0){



        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(degree);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

        }
```

i get error at **int width = bitmap.getWidth(); int height = bitmap.getHeight();**

this my logcat

```
 10-25 11:02:51.689: W/dalvikvm(22013): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bd7438)
10-25 11:02:51.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22013): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 11:02:51.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22013): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-25 11:02:51.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at com.mozaik.tangsel.uploadimage.UploadActivity.decodeFile(UploadActivity.java:580)
10-25 11:02:51.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at com.mozaik.tangsel.uploadimage.UploadActivity$5.onClick(UploadActivity.java:216)
10-25 11:02:51.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
10-25 11:02:51.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16987)
10-25 11:02:51.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-25 11:02:51.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-25 11:02:51.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-25 11:02:51.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
10-25 11:02:51.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 11:02:51.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-25 11:02:51.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
10-25 11:02:51.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
10-25 11:02:51.699: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thanks, sorry for my english

Comment: _"i have problem when get width and height of bitmap"_ what is the problem?

Comment: sorry if my english is bad, i get error at **int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();**

Comment: Your english is fine. Just give more info so people can help you. what **error** you get?

Comment: where does your image comes from? is it from drawable folder?

Comment: AmulyaKhare : i edited my question, please check :)
NoobMe : from sdcard..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `filePath` does not point to a correct file. That is, there is no image at `filePath`. Check the value of `filePath` is correct and this should get resolved.

Comment: oh :O ... my filepath = null... thanks guys,,, now my problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to set your options inJustDecodeBounds before you can set insamplesize

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
                int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
                int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
                String imageType = options.outMimeType;
                if(imageWidth > imageHeight){
                    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,512,256);//<------the size you need if landscape
                }else{
                    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,256,512);//<------the size you need if portrait
                }
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath,options);
```

Comment: after this then make your matrix and rotate